# List function call python

Tags: python-3.x

## 1st Case

```
def modify_list(arg_list):
    arg_list=arg_list.append(5)
    print("Inside function:", arg_list)

i_list=[10,20,30,40,50]
print("Before function call:", i_list)
modify_list(i_list)
print("After function call:", i_list)


Answer:
Before function call: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Inside function: None
After function call: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 5]
```

Question : Why does Inside function returns None. But i_list is modified ?

## 2nd Case

```
def modify_list(arg_list):
    arg_list=arg_list + [60, 70, 80]
    print("Inside function:", arg_list)

i_list=[10,20,30,40,50]
print("Before function call:", i_list)
modify_list(i_list)
print("After function call:", i_list)

Answer:
Before function call: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Inside function: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
After function call: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Question: In this case, why i_list does not get modified as it was in the first case ?

Comment: *"Why does Inside function returns None"*, because `.append()` returns `None`. It modifies list in-place. No new list is created there unlike second case.

Comment: @Austin, Then why does '5' is appended to i_list but not arg_list ?

Comment: 5 is being appended to `arg_list`, but you immediately assign the return value of `append` function to `arg_list` which is `None`. Replace `arg_list=arg_list.append(5)` with `arg_list.append(5)` and see.

Comment: @Austin, Thanks a lot. Got my answer